# How to Make Text Hovering Area not a Full Line?

Tags: html, css, hover

Here's my code:

```
<a href="index.html"><p class="link">Link</p></a>
```

Then in CSS:

```
p.link {color:black}
p.link:hover {color:aqua}
```

How do I make it so that the link doesn't get selected when I'm not directly over it? Because it still changes color when I move my mouse to the left or right side. In other words, how do I make the hover area of the text stop when the text stops? And not a full line?

I thought that the paragraph tag would prevent that, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply logically speaking, you would put your `<p>` tag around your `<a>` tag as a `<p>` defines a whole block of text whereas an `<a>` usually defines a selection of text.

You would wind up with this

```
<p class="link"><a href="index.html">Link</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
a {color:black}
a:hover {color:aqua}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `<p>` tags around the `<a>` tags, and select the `a`s in your css, not the `p`'s. Never put a block element into an inline element. 
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97K8e/2/)